# com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2

I am getting below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet;

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

[jcc][10143][10845][4.19.49] Invalid parameter 1: Parameter is not set nor registered. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815 exception.
```

Hibernate version used - 4.3.10.Final
Spring version used - 4.1.7.RELEASE
DB2 version used - db2jcc4 4.19.49

For fetching the records, we are using HibernateTemplate. Looks like the issue might be because of HibernateTemplate.

Please help on this.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/class-use/DB2Dialect.html)

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: I am migrating hibernate from 3.x.x to 4 along with spring 3.x.x to 4. Issue is exactly in this line                                                        List<String> searchResults = (List<String>) hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(searchCriteria, 0,400);                  
where searchCriteria is an object of DetachedCriteria

Comment: Migrating java from 1.7 to 1.8. We are using dozer also, we are migrating dozer from 3.x.x to 5.5.1.

Comment: We are  using org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

Comment: How did you solve this error?